# Get info and terminate sessions on Azure NetApp Files via API

Tags: c#, azure, netapp

We have a shared drive that everyone has access to

Sometimes we need to rename a folder in this drive but if any user have an open file, we won't be able to rename.

With a few powershell commands I was able to get the user that was accessing the files and even kick them out, being able to rename the folder.

The problem is, we can't use the same technique as the real drive is actually a Azure NetApp Files.

**Problem:**

Be able to get information of who is accessing what on our Azure NetApp Files, similar to `Get-SmbOpenFile` via an API or SDK that I can code in C#.

**Things I've found:**

[NetApp management library for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/resourcemanager.netapp-readme?view=azure-dotnet) <- Doesn't seem to have a way of getting information about what users are accessing what files.

[PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.netappfiles/?view=azps-10.4.1) <- feels like we can use powershell to manage it, but also doesn't seem to have a way of getting the information I need.

I appreciate every solution but please bear in mind that we don't want to change from Azure NetApp Files or overengineer the solution.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hope this reference [helps](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-netapp-files/develop-rest-api-powershell.md)